# Remove milliseconds from timestamp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to remove milliseconds (fraction) from timestamp?

Like for example to_timstamp_ntz('2021-12-28 14:25:36') returns 2021-12-20 14:25:36.000

Comment: try this code:  SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AS date, CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE()) AS time   @ajcoder

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to achieve on the result.
The timestamp data type always contains milliseconds.

Suppose you have such a variable:

```
set t = to_timestamp_ntz('2021-12-28 14:25:36.300');
```

You can truncate the milliseconds and leave the same data type, you will still see zeros but not different values:

```
select date_trunc('SECOND', $t);

+--------------------------+
| DATE_TRUNC('SECOND', $T) |
+--------------------------+
| 2021-12-28 14:25:36.000  |
+--------------------------+
```

You can convert a timestamp value to char or varchar and remove the milliseconds when converting:

```
select to_varchar($t, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

+-----------------------------------------+
| TO_VARCHAR($T, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2021-12-28 14:25:36                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

If you only want to get rid of milliseconds in the displayed result, but not change the type, I suggest changing the session or user settings:

```
alter session set timestamp_ntz_output_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
select $t;

+---------------------+
|         $T          |
+---------------------+
| 2021-12-28 14:25:36 |
+---------------------+
```

Reference: [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html), [TO_VARCHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html), [TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-ntz-output-format)

Comment: Yes, i thought through setting timestamp_ntz_output_format at session level but I want to use this conversion as part of a view creation. So i believe it doesn't work whenever the view refreshes. Is the only other option to set it at account level? I obviously can't alter account. Is there a work around?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to force how a view presents a date/time field to the user querying it?  Snowflake allows this to be a preferences of the end-user, rather than forcing a format.  Could you just allow the end-user to choose how they want the date to be formatted?  If not, change it at the account level.